# LevinRule and SphericalBessels

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I'm currently looking at a simplified problem that approximates another problem I'm looking into. In this simplified problem I at least have an analytic integrand and can easily provide all info on here:

Given the definitions

```
v = 0.6;
g = 1/Sqrt[1 - v^2];

ig[tau1_?NumericQ, tau2_?NumericQ, ωω_?NumericQ, ll_?IntegerQ] :=
(((2 ll + 1) ωω)/(4 Pi^2)) *
 SphericalBesselJ[ll, ωω v g tau1] *
 SphericalBesselJ[ll, ωω v g tau2] *
 Exp[-I ωω g (tau1 - tau2)];
```

I would like to numerically integrate this:

```
f[ω_, l_, pg_, wp_] := 
 2 Re[NIntegrate[
    Exp[-I 1 s] ig[100, 100 - s, ω, l], {s, 0, 40}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
```

But for example `f[2, 1, 15, 25]` etc I get a host of errors like `::slwcon`,`::einc`.

I was wondering if I could use "LevinRule" here and if so what would the options be?

I believe the problem gets worse at large $\omega$ maybe 100 or more. Where even putting the WorkingPrecision upto 40 and PrecisionGoal down to 10, things still scream, if I generate a table of these from 1 to 100 in omega.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two oscillatory parts to your integrand: `Exp[-I 1 s]` and `ig[100, 100 - s, ω, l]`.

However, because you have defined the function `ig` for strictly numerical values of its arguments, `NIntegrate` is not able to "see" its symbolic structure and realize that it is oscillatory with a certain form. Therefore, `"LevinRule"` can only automatically be applied to the `Exp[-I 1 s]` part.

You can see what `"LevinRule"` does:

```
In[199]:= 
NIntegrate`LevinIntegrandReduce[Exp[-I 1 s] ig[100, 100 - s, 2, 1], s]["Rules"]

Out[199]= {"Variables" -> {s}, "AdditiveTerm" -> 0, 
 "Amplitude" -> {ig[100, 100 - s, 2, 1]}, "Kernel" -> {E^(-I s)}, 
 "DifferentialMatrices" -> {{{-I}}}}
```

For more information on the `LevinIntegrandReduce` function, please see [this part of the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337).

However if you define your `ig` function to allow symbolic evaluation, then `NIntegrate` can automatically detect the other oscillatory part of your integrand:

```
In[200]:= 
igsymbolic[tau1_, tau2_, ωω_, 
   ll_] := (((2 ll + 1) ωω)/(4 Pi^2))*
   SphericalBesselJ[ll, ωω v g tau1]*
   SphericalBesselJ[ll, ωω v g tau2]*
   Exp[-I ωω g (tau1 - tau2)];

In[201]:= 
NIntegrate`LevinIntegrandReduce[
  Exp[-I 1 s] igsymbolic[100, 100 - s, 2, 1], s]["Rules"]

Out[201]= {"Variables" -> {s}, "AdditiveTerm" -> 0, 
 "Amplitude" -> {(3 SphericalBesselJ[1, 150])/(2 π^2), 0}, 
 "Kernel" -> {E^(-((7 I s)/2)) SphericalBesselJ[1, (3 (100 - s))/2], 
   E^(-((7 I s)/
     2)) (-(SphericalBesselJ[1, (3 (100 - s))/2]/(3 (100 - s))) + 
      1/2 (SphericalBesselJ[0, (3 (100 - s))/2] - 
         SphericalBesselJ[2, (3 (100 - s))/2]))}, 
 "DifferentialMatrices" -> {{{-((7 I)/2), -(3/2)}, {(
     2 (-2 + 9/4 (100 - s)^2))/(
     3 (100 - s)^2), -((7 I)/2) + 2/(100 - s)}}}}
```

This results in a more efficient integration.

```
In[217]:= 
fsymbolic[ω_, l_, {wp_, pg_, ag_}, mthd_] := 
 2 Re[NIntegrate[
    Exp[-I 1 s] igsymbolic[100, 100 - s, ω, l], {s, 0, 40}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> wp, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, 
    Method -> mthd]]

In[218]:= fsymbolic[2, 1, {25, 15, 18}, Automatic] // Timing

Out[218]= {0.343, -1.925723011031919293641188*10^-6}
```

Scaling up to large values of `l` is also fast:

```
In[219]:= fsymbolic[2, 100, {25, 15, 18}, Automatic] // Timing

Out[219]= {0.608, -0.00002319232924789404095060205}
```

Note that `Method -> Automatic` is fine here since `NIntegrate` automatically detects the oscillatory part of the integrand and selects `LevinRule`.

Comment: that was exactly the kind of thing I was after, thanks a lot..

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the numerical value of the integral is small. Thus in order to appease `NIntegrate`'s error estimator you have to lower the precision/accuracy goals.

Then both `LevinRule` and `Automatic` methods work well:

```
In[356]:= 
f[ω_, l_, {wp_, pg_, ag_}, mthd_] := 
 2 Re[NIntegrate[
    Exp[-I 1 s] ig[100, 100 - s, ω, l], {s, 0, 40}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> wp, AccuracyGoal -> ag, 
    PrecisionGoal -> pg, Method -> mthd]]

In[364]:= f[2, 1, {25, 15, 18}, "LevinRule"]

Out[364]= -1.925723011031859693480016*10^-6

In[366]:= f[2, 1, {25, 15, 18}, Automatic]

Out[366]= -1.925723011031860585537216*10^-6
```

Comment: Out of interest I would still quite like to know how to specify the LevinRule options for this integrand, i.e. what one might put for "Kernal" and that kind of thing.

Comment: You just use `Method->"LevinRule"` as an option of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Sasha: I know you can just do that. I'm wondering about refining the options of LevinRule to better suit the integrand if possible.For example such options as ExcludeForms, AdditiveTerms, Kernal..

Comment: It's interesting to note (for me at least) that the default behaviour (i.e. omitting) AccuracyGoal is to set to Infinity, whereas "Automatic" means processor decides. Whereas PrecisionGoal has the opposite behaviour the default (i.e omitting it from options) is to set it to Auto decide, whereas setting it to infinity would turn it off.

Comment: Thus if you try f[2,1,{25,15,Infinity},Automatic] you set the ag to Infinity (turn it off and use only pg) this gives slwcon. But if you put in f[2,1,{25,15,Automatic},Automatic] you don't get slwcon any more. (http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/NumericalComputation/Integration/NIntegrate.html), I guess it chooses a low enough value of Ag as it likes with this option. I had originally expected ag=Auto to reproduce it's absence...

Comment: Also I'm particularly interested in very high $\omega$ maybe 100, and in reality have a limited WorkinPrecision in my integrand of maybe 10. In which case even turning Ag off->infty, and giving a low precisongoal still gen slwcon