# Sine vs Sinc vs SphericalBesselJ in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I'm evaluating an oscillatory integral numerically, and ran into a weirdness with NIntegrate, which I've boiled down to a simple case for this question.

Consider `NIntegrate[Sin[100 k]/k^5, {k, 100, 250}]`, which evaluates to `-9.59482*10^-13`. Mathematica can handle this integral analytically, writing the solution in terms of Sine integrals. Doing numerical evaluation of the result yields the same answer to 13 digits (`N[Integrate[Sin[100 k]/k^5, {k, 100, 250}], 15]`).

Now, consider writing the Sin function instead as a Sinc function: `NIntegrate[100 Sinc[100 k]/k^4 , {k, 100, 250}]`. Same result.

Finally, consider writing the Sinc function as a SphericalBesselJ function: `NIntegrate[100 SphericalBesselJ[0, 100 k]/k^4 , {k, 100, 250}]`. Note that `SphericalBesselJ[0,x] == Sinc[x]`. Here, Mathematica complains bitterly about doing this integral numerically, before offering the answer of `6.43722*10^-11`.

Why isn't Mathematica choosing the same method to numerically integrate SphericalBesselJ as it is for Sin and Sinc?

Comment: Related: [LevinRule and SphericalBessel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13259/27951)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NIntegrate` may be hardwired to "recognizes" structure in `Sin` and `Sinc` and automatically select better methods, but its heuristics are not smart enough to do that with `SphericalBesselJ`. I would not have known either :-).

Perhaps in further support of that the following executes with no trouble and returns the same results as the others:

```
NIntegrate[100 SphericalBesselJ[0, 100 k]/k^4, {k, 100, 250}, Method -> "LevinRule"] 
(* Out: 9.59482*10^-13 *)
```

Edit

---

To go qualitatively a little further, we can use the beautiful spelunking code provided by [Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov) in his answer to [Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26401/27951). Once you execute his tracing code from that answer, then the following calls return a lot more info:

[image: with Sin]

Note that the above includes a call to `` NIntegrate`ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule ``. This rule is NOT invoked in the `SphericalBesselJ` call:

[image: with bessel]

Comment: As an additional note: `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"` (see e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0771-050X(75)90033-9)) is specifically designed for *finite* oscillatory integrals with explicit sine or cosine factors, so of course `NIntegrate[]` would not consider using it for an integrand with `SphericalBesselJ[]`, even if it is equivalent. (Perhaps Anton might have more to say about this matter...)

Comment: Well, isn't that a curiosity. Guess I should be replacing SphericalBesselJ with Sinc explicitly wherever I can to help out with the method selection, or suggesting an integration method for Mathematica.

Comment: @Jolyon, you might want to look at how to use [`"LevinRule"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337) if you expect to be doing a lot of integrals with spherical Bessels.

Comment: Use [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) to simplify the integrand before integration. `NIntegrate[
 100 SphericalBesselJ[0, 100 k]/k^4 // FunctionExpand, {k, 100, 250}]`

Comment: @Bob, here it works OK, but in general, I would not recommend converting spherical Bessels to their trigonometric form. See e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72744) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117888).